# How to place Recycler views under a drawer menu?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a drawer menu, which allows users to enter filter details, which will update a recycler view list, which is under the filter options. I want the recycler view of results to take up 100% of free space under the filter options in the drawer menu.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp" 
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I need the recycler view to take up the remaining height of the navigation view, after the content of the drawer menu

[Image of current menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XEpq.png)

The image shows the list items (in white) overlapping the content of the drawer menu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the case of your question, please consider adding screenshots of your problem so others can understand your question faster.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda hi, I have attached an image showing the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: You are setting your height here `android:layout_height="350dp" `

Answer (score 0):

Where you are setting your height, use `fill-parent`. I don't know if that's the exact term but it's close.

Comment: I should have added, I have tried this - [this is the result](https://imgur.com/8SjmBUD). I have also tried setting the height to 0dp and the layout_weight to "1" but this makes the list disapear altogether